# Version code error in exporting android apk

Tags: android, android-studio, version

I have an app in the playstore. Its version code is 18.
Now made an update in the app and changed the version code to 19.
Cant upload the apk it shows the error.

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
> Version 18 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that
> might receive version 18 would receive version 28.
>
> Some devices are
> eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will
> receive the APK with the higher version code.

When i checked the AndroidManifest.xml file it shows error in the versioncode section

> This versionCode value (18) is not used; it is always overridden by
> the value specified in the Gradle build script (28) less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> The value of (for example) minSdkVersion is only used if it is not
> specified in the build.gradle build scripts. When specified in the
> Gradle build scripts, the manifest value is ignored and can be
> misleading, so should be removed to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Build.Gradle for your module.

Find a line that says something similar to:

```
versionCode xx
```

"xx" will be an integer.

Delete it.
Rebuild your project.

Or delete it from your manifest and only manage it in your Build.Gradle file.

If a field is defined both in your Build.Gradle and your manifest file, the Build.Gradle overrides the manifest file.

If you're unfamiliar with Gradle, you should get familiar with it. It's extremely powerful and can cause headaches if you don't understand how it works. [Learn more here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the version code from your android manifest and just keep it in gradle file only.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the **build.gradle**(for the App) **sync**-*ed*